# Tablet sessions and clicks discrepancy

Tags: session, click, tablet, google-ads-api

We are a digital media company. Lately for some of our clients whom we do dynamic display ads we have noticed a discrepancy in the tablet clicks and sessions.

I have analyzed our sessions, with our clicks and the clicks we get from adwords and there seems to be loads of discrepancy.

Can anyone help me in figuring why this could have happened? Could there be some issue in the url we are passing in the displays that have an issue on tablets.

[image: See photo]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this case many times and it varies greatly from client to client, campaign to campaign. See if there is some redirect of the campaign to another url, or if the bounce rate is too high, in line with the duration of the sessions, because if the user clicks on the ad and leaves the site quickly, the session is not counted.

Have you checked this guide?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034383?hl=en